# Web API .Net Core controller generator error 'The item specified is not the element of a list.'

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a C# web API solution, using .Net Core 3.1 and EF Core 3.1.10.

When scaffolding a controller from a class and a controller, I get this error:

Running the generator 'controller'...
The item specified is not the element of a list.

It this an EF bug?

Or should I look at the class I'm scaffolding?

Cheers, B.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

Turns out the context missed some things, a constructor and a DbSet. Adding those fixed the problem.